# Automated calculation of a plot margin, dependent on the size of a label

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, r-markdown, margin

For a rather long report, I am trying to unify a number of bar-plots. The plots in general look like this:
[image: Link to picture]

The goal is that all the vertical axis start at the same position (e.g. 2 cm from the left plot-boarder), no matter how long the labels in front of the axis are.

The data that goes into the plot is generated as follows:

```
vector_bar <- as.character(c("Bar1","Bar1","Bar1","Bar1",
                             "Bar2","Bar2","Bar2","Bar2",
                             "thatincrediblylonglabel",
                             "thatincrediblylonglabel",
                             "thatincrediblylonglabel",
                             "thatincrediblylonglabel"))
vector_position <- as.numeric(c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3))
vector_bar_section <- c("section1","section2","section3","section4","section1","section2","section3","section4","section1","section2","section3","section4")
vector_percent <- as.numeric(c(1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0))
vector_yposition <- as.numeric(c(1.05, 1.15, 1.25, 1.35,1.05, 1.15, 1.25, 1.35,1.05, 1.15, 1.25, 1.35))


df <- data.frame(cbind(vector_bar,vector_position,vector_bar_section,vector_percent,vector_yposition))

#Formating
df$vector_percent <- as.numeric(as.character(df$vector_percent))
df$vector_yposition <- as.numeric(as.character(df$vector_yposition))
df$vector_bar <- as.character(df$vector_bar)
```

Now the ggplot-code:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = vector_bar, y = vector_percent, fill = factor(vector_bar_section, levels = rev(c("section1",  "section2", "section3", "section4"))))) +
  geom_label(data = df, aes(x = vector_bar, y = vector_yposition, label = vector_percent),
         colour = "white", fontface = "bold", size = 7.75, show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", data = subset(df), width = 0.65, colour = "white", lwd = 1.3) +
  coord_flip() +
  ggtitle("") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 40, face = "bold"),
    legend.title = element_text(size = 19),
    legend.text = element_text(size = 19, color = "#587992"),
    legend.key.size = unit(1.4, "line"),
    legend.key.width = unit(3.4, "line"),
    axis.text.x = element_text(size = 19, color = "#587992"),
    axis.text.y = element_text(size = 19, color = "#587992"),
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
    axis.title.y = element_blank(),
    legend.position = "top",
    legend.direction = "horizontal",
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    plot.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
    plot.margin = unit(c(0,0,0,Autoplotmargin(df$vector_bar)), units = "in")) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format(), position = "top",breaks =     seq(0,1,0.2)) +
  scale_fill_manual("", values = c("section1"= "#FF0000", 
                               "section2" = "#595959", 
                               "section3" = "#A6A6A6",   
                               "section4" = "#0D0D0D"), guide = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE, nrow = 1)) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c(unique(df$vector_bar)), labels = addline_format(rev(c(unique(df$vector_bar))))) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = 0.5, xend = length(unique(df$vector_bar)) + 0.5, y = 0, yend = 0),color="#587992", size = 1.5) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = length(unique(df$vector_bar)) + 0.5, xend = length(unique(df$vector_bar)) + 0.5, y = 1, yend = 0),color = "#587992", size = 1.5) +
  labs(y = "", x = "")
```

with:

```
addline_format <- function(x,...){
  gsub('\\s ','\n',x)
}
```

Now the interesting part is the function "Autoplotmargin" which I have defined as follows:

```
Autoplotmargin <- function(x) {
y <-  as.numeric(Marginkonstante)-as.numeric(unit(strwidth(strsplit(x[which.max(nchar(x))], "  ", "[")[[1]][1],7.75, units = "in"), units= "in"))
y
}
```

whereas:

```
Marginkonstante <- unit(c(20), units = "in")
```

The idea behind this function is, that I first search for the longest label in `df$vector_bar` and measure it's length in inch:

```
as.numeric(unit(strwidth(strsplit(x[which.max(nchar(x))], "  ", "[")[[1]][1],7.75, units = "in"), units= "in"))
```

Ignore the "strsplit"-section. It is needed because I have line breaks inside the labels and I split the string so that only the characters before the first line break are considered.

So this basically gives me the length of the longest label. I now set the `Marginkonstante` to a value, 20 in the example.

Now the idea is that the `Autoplotmargin` is defined as those 20 inches I set up, subtracted the length of the longest string. Amongst multiple plots this should set up the margin in a way that the vertical axis is positioned at the same place in every plot.

Problem is, that this does not happen. The tendency is right tough: for longer labels, the function `Autoplotmargin` gives me lower values, for shorter labels, it gives me higher values. But the axis are far away from being in the same position for all plots.

What is wrong in my way of thinking?

Important side-notes:

- I do set fig.width in the rmarkdown chunk options, so that all figures are the same width.
- I know there is a solution to this problem by using grid and/or grob functions ([see here for example](https://gist.github.com/tomhopper/faa24797bb44addeba79)). I have looked into that, but can not use these solutions for a number of reasons (not explaining that in detail here, too long).

Thank you for your assistance in advance!

Best,
Fabian

Comment: To make this fully reproducible you should also add the definition of `addline_format`

Comment: Try just `y <-  strwidth(x[which.max(nchar(x))], 7.75, units = "inches")` in `autoplotmargin()`  and in `theme()` use `plot.margin = unit(c(0,0,0,Autoplotmargin(df$vector_bar)), units = "points"))`. So basically use points.

Comment: Dear Martin
Thank you so much for your answer! I added the addline_format function, sorry for missing that one out.

Unfortunately, your suggestion didn't help so far. Using points makes the error smaler, as it is a smaller unit than inches, but I still have the same problem.

When I exchange the lable "thatincrediblylonglabel" (see data-generation-section) with a lable of a different length, then I still get two plots that have the axis-start at a different place.

Comment: Do you use df$vector_bar for both plots? If you really input all possible labels of all plots into yoir function once and use thw resulting number for all plots, it should work. I didnt try it with different data.frames though.

Comment: Thank you so much for your efforts. The idea behind the whole thing is, that the vertical axis of the plots should be aligned without having to input all possible labels of all plots. 
I allowed myself to create a nootebook which you can grab here:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/48o2ifwmo540uw9/AACZhWvW6QSxflfhjgGtTV_0a?dl=0
It contains 2 plots with different data.frames, with different lengths of the labels. Even tough the length of the labels is consiered by the Autoplotmargin-function, the vertical axis are still not aligned, which is what I am trying to do. Well, I'll try again :)

Comment: To whoever is reading this: I seem to have solved the problem. I hope to find the time to post the solution today!

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

As it looks like, my way of thinking was all correct and I just had to change one thing to make it work. In the Autoplotmargin-Function, you choose in which Font-Size you want the string to be measured. In my case, I started with 7.75:

```
Autoplotmargin <- function(x) {
 y <-  as.numeric(Marginkonstante)-as.numeric(unit(strwidth(strsplit(x[which.max(nchar(x))], "  ", "[")[[1]][1],7.75, units = "in"), units= "in"))
y
}
```

Now after playing around with that 7.75 value (in my case decreasing it), all works fine!

In my plot's I get an almost perfect result with 1.3:

```
Autoplotmargin <- function(x) {
y <-  as.numeric(Marginkonstante)-as.numeric(unit(strwidth(strsplit(x[which.max(nchar(x))], "  ", "[")[[1]][1],1.3, units = "in"), units= "in"))
y
}
```